# How to set up @RestController in Spring using already existing jetty-server.xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring

Working on an already existing Spring (not Spring Boot) application, I am trying to use the already existing Jetty server to run a @RestController I have written. Problem is I cannot figure out how to make the application find my controller on startup.

The application is running on Spring version 4.3.9.RELEASE. I've tried using a custom Jetty handler to handle my REST requests but with no success.

#### jetty-server.xml

Used to instantiate a `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` on application start.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

    <context:mbean-export />
    <import resource="jetty-server-base-resource.xml" />

    <bean id="ignoreUnresolvedPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <!-- Specify default values for properties here -->
                <prop key="web.resourceBase">public_html</prop>
                <prop key="web.customerResourceBase">public_html</prop>
                <prop key="web.followAliases">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jettyServer" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">

        <property name="connectors">
            <list>
                <bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                    <property name="port" value="${http.port}" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="handler">
            <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList">
                <property name="handlers">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="com.ANONYMOUS.webstart.ANONYMOUSResourceHandler">
                            <property name="aliases" value="${web.followAliases}" />
                            <property name="directoriesListed" value="true" />
                            <property name="welcomeFiles">
                                <list>
                                    <value>index.html</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                            <property name="baseResource" ref="baseResource"/>
                            <property name="jnlpBuilders">
                                <map>
                                    <entry key="/ANONYMOUSclient.jnlp" value-ref="jnlpBuilder"/>                            
                                    <entry key="/ANONYMOUSclient64bit.jnlp" value-ref="jnlpBuilder64bit"/>
                                </map>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler">
                            <property name="serveIcon" value="false" />
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

#### IssueController

The controller I want to run with the above defined Jetty server.

```java
package com.ANONYMOUS.reactive.api;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/issue")
public class IssueController {
    // Just lots of endpoints defined here
}
```

I want to be ablo to reach the endpoints defined in IssueController through the same port as the Jetty server is using for HTTP. Currently, I only get 404 results.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I'm facing the same problem right now. @anderseriksson did you ever find a solution for this?